# Error: Could not find or load main class RDDBasics.CreatingSparkContextWithSparkSession

Tags: eclipse, apache-spark, session

[image]
[image]

package RDDBasics

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object CreatingSparkContextWithSparkSession {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

  val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("Creating Spark context with spark session")
  .getOrCreate()

  val array = Array(1,2,3,4,5)

  val arrayRDD = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(array, 1)
  arrayRDD.foreach(println)
```

I am having the above error in eclipse can anyone please help?

[image]

Comment: your project has some errors , can show those errors click on errors window ?

Comment: hello srinivas, i have added the error window image, can you please help me with the answer?

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml here ? & also close unnecessary project ? then attache error screenshot agian.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with `Scala version`. In class path scala version `2.12`& Inside pom.xml scala version `2.11`

1. Change Scala version from 2.12 to 2.11 in class path or
2. Inside pom.xml,Replace Scala version 2.11 with 2.12

Comment: I am unable to find Scala in pom.xml, can you help me where should i get Scala to change the version?

Comment: post pom.xml i tell you

Comment: added the pom.xml

Comment: Change _2.11 to _2.12 & clean the project & rebuild again.

Comment: Can you let me know the steps to change the version and to clean and rebuilding again?

Comment: ok, just replace wherever you find _2.11 to _2.12 after replacing your ide atomically detect changes & it will bring those libs, right click on pom.xml files & find maven plugin options - maven clean, compile

Comment: This video will help you - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vid_Ss-5cPI

Comment: Thanks, I will do accordingly.

Comment: Sure i will do that

Comment: I am unable to open my Eclipse and the error is please choose another workspace as 'C:User/sammy/workspace is currently in use. Can you please advise? i didn't change version and clean maven yet.

Comment: I tried but unable to delete .lock file from .metada folder. It is showing the action can't be completed because the file is open in eclipse.exe

Comment: Why don't you try using intillij ide instead of eclipse. Intillij community edition..

Comment: Ok sure, I will try. Thanks

Comment: Is this issue fixed ??

Comment: Yes, I re-installed eclipse.

Comment: Can you please accept answer or upvote if it helps you to solve problem

Comment: I am unable to find that option. Where should i have option to upvote?